# How can I detect one contour within another with Opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to make a white outline (white plates of a car) inside a yellow outline (a taxi), but I do not even recognize the white color of that plate in HSV, how can I solve this ?. In the code i am using trackbars to be able to change the values of RGB to my free will.
Thanks!

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)


def dibujarblanco(maskblanco,color):


    _,contornos,_=cv2.findContours(maskblanco, 
cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for c in contornos:
                area = cv2.contourArea(c)
                    if area > 200:

                        nuevocontorno = cv2.convexHull(c)
                        cv2.drawContours(frame, [nuevocontorno], 0, color,3)


def nothing(x):
    pass
video = cv2.VideoCapture("taxismenor.mp4")

cv2.namedWindow("Barras Blanco")

cv2.createTrackbar("B", "Barras Blanco", 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("G", "Barras Blanco", 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("R", "Barras Blanco", 0, 255, nothing)

while(1):
    _, frame=video.read()
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)  

    B = cv2.getTrackbarPos("B", "Barras Blanco")
    G = cv2.getTrackbarPos("G", "Barras Blanco")
    R = cv2.getTrackbarPos("R", "Barras Blanco")

    blanco = np.uint8([[[B, G, R]]])
    hsvBlanco = cv2.cvtColor(blanco,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    lowerLimitb = np.uint8([hsvBlanco[0][0][0]-10,100,100])
    upperLimitb = np.uint8([hsvBlanco[0][0][0]+10,255,255])


    maskblanco = cv2.inRange(hsv, lowerLimitb, upperLimitb)                    


    dibujarblanco(maskblanco,(0,0,255))

    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
    cv2.imshow("maskblanco", maskblanco)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if key == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IELLU.jpg) is the result of trying outline white color of plates. Nothing, it does not work.

Comment: Where is your image? You should show the example image and your expected result image to exactly show what you want.

Comment: small noise comes out when I try to contour the white color and nothing comes out, instead a black screen and a few small white dots, instead detecting the yellow contour it comes out perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could firstly set the contour(a taix) to the color of the background of image.Then, copy this image to detect next contour.

Comment: i alredy countour the taxi, now i want to recognize the white plate of this

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cv.findContours()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a) to extract the whole contours hierarchy

```
image, contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(image, mode, method[, contours[, hierarchy[, offset]]])
```

> **hierarchy**
>
> Optional output vector (e.g. std::vector), containing information about the image topology. It has as many elements as the number of contours. For each i-th contour contours[i], the elements hierarchy[i][0] , hierarchy[i][1] , hierarchy[i][2] , and hierarchy[i][3] are set to 0-based indices in contours of the next and previous contours at the same hierarchical level, the first child contour and the parent contour, respectively. If for the contour i there are no next, previous, parent, or nested contours, the corresponding elements of hierarchy[i] will be negative.